# iOS reflow layout with UIButtons that change size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder, autolayout

I am building an iOS app that uses a UILabel to present a question at the top of the screen and then displays a number of UIButtons with text in the titleLabel to get the answer. I am using this View to display many different questions at different times and each question and set of answers has a different number of words in it. As a result, each UIButton can end up with a very different number of words, which creates a layout problem. I am currently using some code like this:

```
self.firstAnswer.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.firstAnswer.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
self.firstAnswer.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.firstAnswer sizeToFit];
```

which allows the buttons to resize itself to keep all the text onscreen. It also, however, causes the uibuttons to overlap vertically when a button resizes too much vertically (ie, the titleLabel is now 4 lines instead of 1). Is there any way to cause a button that is vertically below another button that has resized itself to move down to make room for the newly resized button?

Answer (score 1):

What if you update the position of the following buttons based on the new height of the firstAnswer:

```
self.secondItem.frame = CGRectMake(self.secondButton.frame.origin.x, 
                                   self.firstAnswer.frame.origin.y + self.firstAnswer.frame.size.height + 10,
                                   self.secondButton.frame.size.width, 
                                   self.secondButton.frame.size.height);
```

If you've got multiple other items, you can reposition them after each subsequent one, or use a general offset for all.

EDIT:
If multiple buttons follow, you cold also just put them inside a single tranparent UIView, then just offset that UIView alone.

Comment: This is absolutely my plan if I can't find a way to do it more simply. I am pretty new to iOS, but I feel like I should be able to click something in IB to make the layout work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use auto layout and give the buttons vertical spacing constraints to their nearest top and bottom neighbors. This will keep the spacing the same no matter how many lines you need for the button.

Comment: For some reason doing this seems to short circuit the sizeToFit method and I end up with text that runs right off the right side of the screen. Your general solution is the sort of thing that I feel like **should** work, but I haven't made it work yet.

Comment: @enkrates, yeah, it does seem that sizeToFit sometimes doesn't play well with auto layout.